# Application.OnTime & BeforeClose

Tags: excel, vba

Just want to ask if why do I keep receiving this error?

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'OnTime' of object'_Application' failed

So, I'm trying to close my workbook but whenever I'm doing it, the error shows. The highlighted line after clicking the Debug button is `Application.OnTime timeCheck, "SaveThis", , False` in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` sub. What seems to be the problem here?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 'place in ThisWorkbook
 timeCheck = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
 Application.OnTime timeCheck, "SaveThis"
End Sub

Sub SaveThis() 'place in Module
 timeCheck = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ThisWorkbook.Save
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.OnTime timeCheck, "SaveThis"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 'place in ThisWorkbook
 Application.OnTime timeCheck, "SaveThis", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: You, firstly, did not set the time in `timeCheck` and `Application.OnTime` need it. Then, using it in `BeforeClose` event for such a thing is useless. Since "SaveThis" is called inside the `Sub` "SaveThis", the `Sub` will be called next time when the workbook is open, even if `Workbook_Open` event will not be fired. But it will be, anyhow... :) `OnTime` actions will be removed only when Excel `Application` will be closed/quit.

Comment: Do you declare `timeCheck` as a global variable at the top of your module?  You need to do that if you want to use its value when cancelling the `OnTime`

Comment: @TimWilliams yes `timeCheck` is declared as global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to schedule a call to `SaveThis()` in the future, right when the application is about to close. Why would you want to do that?, if the error never happened, then how will you guarantee that the call happens when the workbook is already closed?

If what you meant to do is save the workbook before closing the workbook, then you will need to change your code as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 'place in ThisWorkbook
 timeCheck = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
 Application.OnTime timeCheck, "SaveThis"
End Sub

Sub SaveThis() 
 timeCheck = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
 SaveRightNow     ' This is a new sub that you will need to add
 Application.OnTime timeCheck, "SaveThis"
End Sub

Sub SaveRightNow()
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ThisWorkbook.Save
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 'place in ThisWorkbook
  SaveRightNow  ' Saves the workbook without having to schedule a call in the future
End Sub
```